# Styling via inline style works, styling via external style sheet doesn't

Tags: css, html-heading

I was trying to remove extra margin/padding around the `H1` tag. Suggestions from other posts included setting the top/bottom margins of the `H1` tag to `0`, 
using a negative margin, and changing the `line-height`. Nothing worked...

So I used Firebug to see if it could help. Sure enough there was a margin around the `H1` when I looked at the Layout in Firebug. When I changed the number to `0`, it added:

`style="margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px;"`

to the `H1` tag (as was suggested in other posts) and it fixed the issue. However when I added an entry to the external CSS file to style the `H1` tag there, the styling **didn't** work (i.e. the `margin`/`padding` was back).

Does this mean there's a bug in my external CSS?

Thank you!!

Ken

Comment: Post your CSS and HTML so we can see what you have tried.

Comment: internal stylesheet have more priority than external.. try to find style for H1 there already in your external css file. If so, modify there..  Use css reset and line-height for h1..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline style is the highest priority. Your problem resides in prioritizing your rules.

Check out [This article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: as a matter of fact inline style does not overwrite !important declarations

Comment: as a sidenote to the OP, inline style is the devil. No but's ... it's the devil I said!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class to your H1 tag like "", and through that class you can style in external sheet.